# Azure App Service "Local Written Bytes"

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-app-service-plans

I have an app service running that has 8 instances running in the service plan.

The app is written in asp dotnet core, it's an older version than is currently available.

Occasionally I have an issue where the servers start returning a high number of 5xx errors after a period of sustained load.

It appears that only one instance is having an issue - which is causing the failed request rate to climb.

I've noticed that there is a corresponding increase in the "locally written bytes" on the instance that is having problems - I am not writing any data locally so I am confused as to what this metric is actually measuring. In addition the number of open connections goes high and then stays high - rebooting the problematic instance doesn't seem to achieve anything.

The only thing I suspect is that we are copying data from a user's request straight into Azure Blob Store using the `UploadFromStreamAsync` from the `HttpRequest.Body` - with the data coming from a mobile phone app.

Microsoft support suggested we swapped to using local cache as an option to reduce issues with storage, however this has not resolved the issue.

Can anyone tell me what is the "locally written bytes" actually measuring? There is little documentation on this metric that I can find in google.